# Spring integration: how to specify a custom task executor for QueueChannel

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I'm writing a Spring Integration application which receives messages from an input system, transforms them and sends them to an output system. The connection to the output system is not always available. The messages from the input system can come at any moment. In case if they are coming when the output system is not available, they shouldn't be lost and send eventually when the output system is available. So I store the messages from the input system in a QueueChannel:

```kotlin
@Configuration
class TcInFlowConfiguration {

  @Bean
  fun tcInFlow(
    @Qualifier(TC_MESSAGE_LISTENER) listener: MessageProducerSupport,
    @Qualifier(TC_MESSAGE_CHANNEL) messageChannel: MessageChannel
  ): IntegrationFlow {
    
    return IntegrationFlow
      .from(listener)      
      .transform { msg: ByteArray -> RamsesTcFrame.deserialize(msg) }      
      .channel(messageChannel)
      .get()
  }  

  @Bean
  @Qualifier(TC_MESSAGE_CHANNEL)
  fun tcMessageChannel(): MessageChannel {    
    return MessageChannels.queue().get()
  }
```

The app receives an API call to open/close the connection to the output system, so I create and remove the output integration flow programmatically via `IntegrationFlowContext`:

```kotlin
val outFlow = IntegrationFlow
      .from(TC_MESSAGE_CHANNEL)      
      .handle(createMessageSender())
      .get()

integrationFlowContext.registration(outFlow).register()
```

When the messages are polled from the queue to be processed by the outFlow, the default Spring task executor is used (I see "scheduling-1" as a thread name in logs). The problem is that I have multiple independent integration flows in the app with the multiple queue channels, so they all got mixed up by being processed by the same task executor. What I want is to process each flow in its own dedicated thread, so the flows won't block each other. How can I achieve this?

Spring Boot v3.0.2, Spring v6.0.4

I tried setting a task scheduler for my QueueChannel:

```kotlin
val queueChannel = MessageChannels.queue().get()
queueChannel.setTaskScheduler(taskScheduler)
```

It didn't have any effect, taskScheduler seems to be simply not used by QueueChannel implementation.

I tried using `ExecutorChannel` instead of `QueueChannel` which supports setting a custom `Executor`. Unfortunately, ExecutorChannel doesn't buffer messages in memory, so if there are no subscribers to the channel the messages are lost.

Finally, I tried defining a poller in the outFlow to poll the messages from the QueueChannel:

```
IntegrationFlow
  .from(TC_MESSAGE_CHANNEL) 
  .handle(createMessageSender()) { e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(10).taskExecutor(taskExecutor)) }  
  .get()
```

This didn't work either. After the connection to the output system is closed and the outFlow is removed, the intermediate channel created by the poller remains in Spring context. So when the new message arrives in QueueChannel it goes to that intermediate channel which is a subscribable channel without subscribers, so the message is lost.

Answer (score 0):

That's correct. The `QueueChannel` is just a buffer for messages. It really only matters how you consume messages from there. And the common way is to use a `PollingConsumer` like you do with that `e.poller()`. It is also correct to configure a `taskExecutor()` if you don't like to have your messages to be consumed by a `TaskScheduler`'s thread. Not sure what you talk about an "intermediate channel" since it doesn't look like you have one declared in your `outFlow`. You have that `.from(TC_MESSAGE_CHANNEL)` and then immediately a `handle()` with a proper poller. So, no any extra channel in between or after. Unless you do something else in your `createMessageSender()`.

I would suggest do not have a dynamic flow, but rather singleton one for that output system. The `QueueChannel` can be configured for a persistent message store and poller can be transactional. So, if no connection to a target system, the transaction is going to be rolled back and message remains in the store: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/system-management.html#message-store.

You also can just `stop()` a polling consumer for that `handle()` when no connection, so no messages are polled from the queue at that moment.

Comment: The tesing that I'm doing is:
1. send an input message - verify it's saved in the queue
2. register out flow - verify the message is taken from the queue and sent 
3. de-register out flow
4. send another input message - verify it's saved in the queue

Without the poller all assertions hold. But with the poller the last one breaks. When I send the message after de-registering the flow, the message is still taken from the queue and an exception is thrown because there are no subscribers for the channel.

Comment: The exception is: org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel 'application.org.springframework.integration.dsl.StandardIntegrationFlow#0.channel#1'

Comment: Not sure what this StandardIntegrationFlow#0.channel#1 is but it seems to be added by the out flow because before the first flow registration everything works fine.

Comment: OK. Now it is only would be possible to understand if you would share with us a simple project to reproduce and play with.

Comment: Let's also see if you can get use of dedicated Kotlin DSL instead: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/kotlin-dsl.html#kotlin-dsl !